# How to remove unwanted `.0` s in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

How can I convert the components of a column of my pandas DataFrame from float type to *actual* string?

Initially when I `read_csv` them they display in Scientific notation:

e.g. 1.04983E+13

I used this following line to change the display type to show all digits with no decimal:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
```

which seems to work initially (no decimal shown!):

```
sample_df['gpid'][0:2]
0    10498310800133
1   767838527881217
```

However, when I try to make a list out of it, it clearly includes the decimal `.0` in front of each and every component

```
list(sample_df['gpid'])[0:2]
[10498310800133.0, 767838527881217.0]
```

How can I avoid this unwanted `.0`? [this has been an annoying thing for the entire day yesterday...]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be confusing objects with their representations. This DataFrame holds `float`s. You can represent these how you like (as strings) but when you change display options the objects remain the same. Converting to a list sends these `float` objects into a python `list` which has it's own representation of `float`s (unrelated to `pandas`) and will always display the `.0`.

You can't change the formatting of a python `list`. It is inbuilt. You could convert these `float`s to `int`s, by doing

```
list(map(int, sample_df['gpid']))[0:2]
[10498310800133, 767838527881217]
```

but be aware you are making new objects, not simply changing their representations. This means any non-integer floats (ie. doesn't end in `.0`) will be converted to integers.

To convert the pandas values to strings, do

```
sample_df['gpid'] = sample_df['gpid'].apply(lambda f: format(f, '.0f'))
```

Output:

```
              gpid
0   10498310800133
1  767838527881217
```

Answer (score 0):

To force `int` use:

```
list(sample_df['gpid'].astype('int64'))[0:2]
```

Your column is obviously type `float64` due to floating point numbers of `nan`.